# Is there any way to automatically use a specific terminal profile for a specific host?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Whenever I connect to production server using ssh from my terminal, is there any way to automatically change the appearance of the Ubuntu terminal with special color so that I don't execute some stupid commands thinking that I am running in my local system?

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to reverse the prompt, so it is easily seen, that you're on a different system:

```
 PS1="$(tput rev)$LOGNAME@$(uname -n)>$(tput sgr0)> "
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome Terminal, you can create different profiles for different purposes using `File->New Profile...`. Each profile can have their own terminal title, custom command, colors, background and other settings.